# How to understand the idiom 'steep in'

Tags: meaning, idioms

Source: Merriam Webster

> Definition of steep in
> 1: to make (someone) know and understand a lot about (something)
> Prior to his trip, he spent a few weeks steeping himself in the language.
> —often used as (be) steeped in
> She was steeped in the classics.
> 2—used as (be) steeped in to say that there is a lot of something associated with a place, time, etc.
> an area steeped in history

I'm not what the general meaning of this idiom. I get the impression that a place or person instills values and knowledge into another person/thing from a philosophy or something.

Answer (score 3):

As you have guessed, **steeped in the classics** and similar phrases are examples of figurative language. They are not meant to be taken literally.

Our most common literal use of the word **steep** suggests a contrary meaning to the one you have described. We let tea **steep** in hot water in order to extract the flavor from the tea leaves. Thus, the water gets flavored, not the tea.

It's a related use of **steep** that we're after here. Collins Dictionary provides a [useful definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/steep):

> **4 VERB**
> To steep food in a liquid means to put the food in the liquid for some time so that the food gets flavour from the liquid.
>
> . . . green beans steeped in olive oil.

The Cambridge Dictionary provides a [similar definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steep) and even better examples:

> ***verb***
> to cause to stay in a liquid, especially in order to become soft or clean, or to improve flavour:
>
> Leave the cloth to steep in the dye overnight.
>
> We had pears steeped in red wine for dessert.

Clearly, it is the cloth that is absorbing the dye, not the other way around. Likewise, the pears have been improved by absorbing the wine. That is why the sentence reads **we had pears** rather than **we had wine**.

The idea is that if you grow up with constant exposure to classical literature (etc.) then you will develop some mastery of the subject.